# Comparing Map.Entry object with a double variable

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator

This is kind of basic question. I am iterating a map using `iterator` and I have a double variable `m_asim`. I need to know how do I compare the value of map with the double variable?

My code:

```
for(Map mp:dblist){
            Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
                    //Need to know how to compare in next line
                    if(pair.getValue() >= m_asim) // this line give me error
                    {}

                    it.remove(); 
                }
        }
```

Error:

```
operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Object,double
```

Comment: What type are you expecting pair.getValue() to be?

Comment: I am expecting it to be "Double"

Comment: If that's the case, you need the type of the map and its entries to reflect that. You've got only `Map` and `Map.Entry`, not `Map<someclass, Double>` and `Map.Entry<someclass, Double>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can go is to declare the Map and the Iterator with Generics. This way the entry value will be typed as a double.

Assuming the Map has a string key and a double value, you could do this:

```
    Iterator<Entry<String, Double>> it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Double> pair = it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        //Need to know how to compare in next line
        if(pair.getValue() >= m_asim) // this line give me error
        {}

        it.remove(); 
    }
```